# Find matching record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables;
 [image]

```
1)Employee      (EmployeeId,Name)
2)Role          (RoleId,RoleName)
3)EmployeeRole  (EmployeeId,RoleId)
```

I have that records;

I want to do that i'll give the EmployeeId and query must give me the reply which users have the same role with Employee which i gave the EmployeeID.

For example;

I give the EmployeeID is 1 , i want to see Employees have roles 1,2,3 (all of them, i dont want to get 1 or 2 or 1,2 or 1,3 i want 1,2,3 all roles must be match)

How can i do can you help me?

I've try that but i didn't work that is my query;

```
DECLARE @Query varchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @RoleID INT
DECLARE crsEmployeeRole CURSOR FOR
SELECT RoleID FROM Employee_Role where EmployeeID = 2340
OPEN crsEmployeeRole
FETCH NEXT FROM crsEmployeeRole INTO @RoleID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
            SET @Query = @Query + 'select EmployeeID into #temp'+cast(@RoleID as varchar(max))+' from Employee_Role where RoleID = '+cast(@RoleID as varchar(max))+' '
            FETCH NEXT FROM crsEmployeeRole INTO @RoleID
       END
CLOSE crsEmployeeRole
DEALLOCATE crsEmployeeRole

exec(@Query)

DECLARE @Query2 varchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @RoleID2 INT
DECLARE crsEmployeeRole CURSOR FOR
SELECT RoleID FROM Employee_Role where EmployeeID = 2340
OPEN crsEmployeeRole
FETCH NEXT FROM crsEmployeeRole INTO @RoleID2
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
             if(@Query2 = '')
             SET @Query2 = 'SELECT t1.* FROM #temp'+cast(@RoleID2 as varchar(max))+' t1'
             else
             SET @Query2 = @Query2 + ' inner join #temp'+cast(@RoleID2 as varchar(max))+' on t1.EmployeeID = #temp'+cast(@RoleID2 as varchar(max))+'.EmployeeID'
             FETCH NEXT FROM crsEmployeeRole INTO @RoleID2
       END
CLOSE crsEmployeeRole
DEALLOCATE crsEmployeeRole

exec(@Query2)
```

Comment: you need to learn how to use `JOINS` and `WHERE` clauses. There are multiple tutorials online which will teach you about those two items, good luck. Also, you will want to add any attempt you have made to write this query to your post or else you will probably begin to receive down-votes.

Comment: Any effort form your side, SO gives suggestions, improvements and enhancements to your efforts. Appreciate any effort from your end

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work, so that we can help you with your query.

Comment: Here is a good SQL tutorial: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/sql-tutorial/  Go through it and then try to apply your learnings to your own situation. If you get stuck, post your code and we can help you

Comment: @RyanWilson thnx for your suggestion, i know a lot of thing about joins and where clauses. That is complicated problem.

Comment: @Ka_Ya Cursors are a last resort in SQL, you should be going for a set based approach if at all possible. Your expected results would be helpful to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**that will work.. GL...**

```
DECLARE @Query varchar(max) = ''

DECLARE @DeleteTemp varchar(max) = ''

DECLARE @RoleID INT

DECLARE crsEmployeeRole CURSOR FOR

SELECT RoleID FROM Employee_Role where EmployeeID = 1

OPEN crsEmployeeRole

FETCH NEXT FROM crsEmployeeRole INTO @RoleID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

       BEGIN

             SET @DeleteTemp = 'if OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..##temp'+cast(@RoleID as varchar(max))+''') is not null begin DROP TABLE ##temp'+cast(@RoleID as varchar(max))+' end'

             exec (@DeleteTemp)

             SET @Query = @Query + 'select PersonelID into ##temp'+cast(@RoleID as varchar(max))+' from Employee_Role where RoleID = '+cast(@RoleID as varchar(max))+' '      

             FETCH NEXT FROM crsEmployeeRole INTO @RoleID

       END

CLOSE crsEmployeeRole

DEALLOCATE crsEmployeeRole

exec (@Query)

DECLARE @Query2 varchar(max) = ''

DECLARE @RoleID2 INT

DECLARE crsEmployeeRole CURSOR FOR

SELECT RoleID FROM Employee_Role where EmployeeID = 1

OPEN crsEmployeeRole

FETCH NEXT FROM crsEmployeeRole INTO @RoleID2

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

       BEGIN

             if(@Query2 = '')

             SET @Query2 = 'SELECT t1.* FROM ##temp'+cast(@RoleID2 as varchar(max))+' t1'

             else
             SET @Query2 = @Query2 + ' inner join ##temp'+cast(@RoleID2 as varchar(max))+' on t1.PersonelID = ##temp'+cast(@RoleID2 as varchar(max))+'.PersonelID'

             FETCH NEXT FROM crsEmployeeRole INTO @RoleID2

       END

CLOSE crsEmployeeRole

DEALLOCATE crsEmployeeRole

exec(@Query2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can count the matching roles using a `join` and `group by`:

```
select employee_id, count(*)
from employee_role er join
     employee_role er1
     on er.role_id = er1.role_id
where er1.employee_id = @id
group by er.employee_id;
```

A `having` clause or subquery, then does what you want:

```
select employee_id, count(*)
from employee_role er join
     (select er1.*, count(*) over () as cnt
      from employee_role er1
      where er1.employee_id = @id
     ) er1
     on er.role_id = er1.role_id
group by er.employee_id, cnt
having count(*) = cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the ids of the employees then use a cte:

```
with cte as (select roleid from employee_role where employeeid = 1)
select employeeid
from employee_role
where roleid in (select roleid from cte) and employeeid <> 1
group by employeeid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from cte)
```

If you also want the names of the employees join the above query to the table `employee`:

```
with cte as (select roleid from employee_role where employeeid = 1)
select e.*
from employee e inner join (
    select employeeid
    from employee_role
    where roleid in (select roleid from cte) and employeeid <> 1
    group by employeeid
    having count(*) = (select count(*) from cte)
) g on g.employeeid = e.employeeid
```

Comment: A little more detail as to what your queries are doing would be helpful for the OP.

Comment: From the OP's comment: *i know a lot of thing about joins and where clauses*. I think that the code is very simple and if the OP needs any clarification then I will explain.

Comment: Isn't this just counting how many roles EmployeeID 1 has and matching that to any others with the same number of roles or did I miss something? Something else looks to be needed to specifically check all roles match, rather than the count

Comment: @DBAMark Yes you are missing `where roleid in (select roleid from cte)`. So if empid = 1 has 3 roles: 1, 2 and 3 then the selected employee will have 3 roles from 1,2,3 which means exactly the same roles.

Comment: @forpas I will respectfully disagree with you about the OP "knowing a lot of things" as they are using a Cursor to try and achieve their desired results. And regardless of whether the OP understands it or not, your answer should have comments and an explanation of your answer for others who may view this post.

Comment: @forpas I've tested this and it looks like it'll do the trick, you just have a typo in both statements (FROM FROM) but once that's taken out it looks to work :)

Comment: Thnx for your help , i found the solution.

Comment: @Ka_Ya really? Is this the solution you were looking for?

Comment: Şahin Sarul's answer enough for me @forpas, thnx for your help too.

Comment: @Ka_Ya I can't tell if it answers your question because I can't read it. All I'm asking is: is this the kind of answer you were looking for? If so you should have mentioned it in your question. When somebody asks a question about sql in SO usually they prefer the simpler and more efficient solution. You decided the opposite although you got 3 other answers simpler and far more efficient. Isn't it strange?

Comment: @forpas u're right, your answer is working too and simpler, i said thank you to you for your effort but i want to write with cursors and upvote the answer which answer have got cursor

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #EMPLOYEE
(
  EMPLOYEEID INT NOT NULL
, NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #EMPLOYEE VALUES
  (1, 'John')
, (2, 'Lisa')
, (3, 'Emilia')
, (4, 'Jacob')
, (5, 'Henry')

CREATE TABLE #ROLE
(
  ROLEID INT NOT NULL
, ROLENAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #ROLE VALUES
  (1, 'helper')
, (2, 'viewer')
, (3, 'designer')

CREATE TABLE #EMPLOYEE_ROLE
(
  EMPLOYEEID INT NOT NULL
, ROLEID INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #EMPLOYEE_ROLE VALUES
  (1, 1)
, (1, 2)
, (1, 3)
, (2, 2)
, (2, 3)
, (3, 1)
, (3, 2)
, (3, 3)
, (4, 1)
, (5, 1)


SELECT #EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEEID
     , #EMPLOYEE.NAME 
FROM #EMPLOYEE
INNER JOIN #EMPLOYEE_ROLE 
ON #EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEEID = #EMPLOYEE_ROLE.EMPLOYEEID
  WHERE #EMPLOYEE_ROLE.ROLEID IN
(  
--EMPLOYEE-ROLES
SELECT DISTINCT ER.ROLEID
FROM #EMPLOYEE E
INNER JOIN #EMPLOYEE_ROLE ER
ON E.EMPLOYEEID = ER.EMPLOYEEID
WHERE E.EMPLOYEEID = 5  --HERE IS THE PARAMETER
)
GROUP BY #EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEEID
       , #EMPLOYEE.NAME
```

If you put 5 in the WHERE clause you have

```
3   Emilia
5   Henry
4   Jacob
1   John
```

Hope it helps